# ¿Cómo obtener URL absoluta de imagen en DjangoRestFramework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, djangorestframework

Estoy realizando una API en la que añado por un método un campo con un array en la que tiene 3 url de imagenes para mostrarla como preview.

Este es mi código:

### Serializer

```
class TendenciaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productos_tendencia = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    preview = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = Tendencia
    fields = ['id','nombre','productos_tendencia','contador_like','contador_productos','preview']

    def get_preview(self, tendencia):
        qs = Producto.objects.filter(tendencia=tendencia)
        fotos_preview = []
        for q in qs:
            fotos = Foto.objects.filter(producto=q)
            fotos_preview.append({'foto':fotos[0].path.url})
        return fotos_preview
```

### ViewSet

```
class TendenciaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tendencia.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TendenciaSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    http_method_names = ['get','post']
```

### Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El valor de foto me devuelve la ruta relativa del archivo pero en otras funciones me devuelve la ruta empezando con el dominio. Necesito añadir la ruta completa para que funcione cuando lo pase a producción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que en tu método `get_preview()`:

```
    for q in qs:
        fotos = Foto.objects.filter(producto=q)
        fotos_preview.append({'foto':fotos[0].path.url})
    return fotos_preview
```

obtienes las fotos llamando directamente al url, en situaciones normales los serializadores de DRF tienen una propiedad `context` que incluye el request de la vista, adaptando el context a tu funcion quedaria así:

```
def get_preview(self, tendencia):
    qs = Producto.objects.filter(tendencia=tendencia)
    fotos_preview = []
    for q in qs:
        fotos = Foto.objects.filter(producto=q)
        request = self.context.get('request')
        foto_url = request.build_absolute_uri(fotos[0].path.url})
        fotos_preview.append({'foto': foto_url)
    return fotos_preview
```

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias.